# ruby method_alias in inherited class

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, alias-method, class-eval

I'm deeping into ruby metaprogramming and have next question.
Example:

```
module ExampleAliaser
  def do_example_alias(prefix=:origin)

    class_eval  <<-EOS
       class << self 
           alias_method :#{prefix}_example, :example
           def example
              puts "in aliase will call :#{prefix}_example"
              #{prefix}_example
           end  
        end
    EOS

  end   
end  

class Example1
 def self.example
    puts "Example"
 end 
end


Example1.extend(ExampleAliaser)

class Example1 
 do_example_alias(:origin)
end
class Example2 <  Example1
 do_example_alias(:origin)
end



     Example1.example
    in aliase will call :origin_example
    Example
     => nil 

     Example2.example
in aliase will call :origin_example
in aliase will call :origin_example
in aliase will call :origin_example
    SystemStackError: stack level too deep
        from /Users/igorfedoronchuk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
    Maybe IRB bug!!
```

So when mixin used 2 times it causes error.
What is the best way to fix such things? How to determine that mixing exists and remove it before new mixing

Comment: stack level too deep , scroll down source block

Comment: doh, didn't notice the scrollbar :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the definition of methods to see why this is happening.

You first define `Example1::example` in the class definition of `Example1`. It writes a string to the console.

Then you extend `ExampleAliaser`. When you call `Example1::do_example_alias`, you then alias the method `example` to `origin_example` and redefine the method `example` to write a different string to the console and call `origin_example`.

Then you define the class `Example2` to inherit from `Example1`, which now has two methods defined on it: `origin_example` and `example`. When you call `Example2::do_example_alias`, you alias the method `example` to `origin_example`. But remember that `example` was already redefined to call `origin_example`. So effectively, `Example2::example` will call itself until you run out of room on the stack.

---

If you want to avoid double-aliasing, you could include some kind of guard in `do_example_alias`:

```
def do_example_alias(prefix = :origin)
  unless methods.include?("#{prefix}_example")
    # do the aliasing
  end
end
```

You can also `undef :method_name` in subclasses to remove methods that you no longer want defined.

Comment: Yes , I understand this, my qustion is about how to change module so it can find out it was extended earlier and redefine aliases again

Comment: I mean how to reselve such conflicts, if module was extended earlier.
Also if Example2 will call do_example_alias(:other_prefix), how to remove previously defined aliases?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even see your last paragraph after the code block. I'll update my answer.